# How to stop Div from moving when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, browser, resize, css-float

I have a sidebar and an area for the content of my website. The sidebar is fixed, but the page content can be scrolled. However when the browser window is resized, the page content div is being pushed to the left as it is set to float to the right, and I would like it to never go further to the left than it is (currently it will slowly hide under the sidebar content). You can see what's happening in the screenshots below:

The first screenshot shows the fullscreen browser window and the one below it shows what it's like when the browser window is resized:

[image: Fullscreen]

[image: Resized]

How can I get the page content to resize, centered and never go past where the sidebar is, as currently the image and the text below it will get hidden underneath the sidebar and instead would like it to resize against the sidebar. The code I have is below.

```css
/* Main CSS */
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Futura PT", sans-serif;
}

    /* Sidebar */
#sidebar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
}


/* Page Content */
#pageContentContainer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#pageContent {
    float: right;
    width: 78%;
    background-color: #212121;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo/mdLogo.png"></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3D MODELLING</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="socialLinks">
            <a href="#/" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-3x"></a>
            <a href="#/" class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></a>
            <a href="#/" class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-3x"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="pageContentContainer">
        <div id="pageContent">
            <!-- Parallax -->
            <div class="parallaxImage1"></div>

            <div class="parallaxContent">
                <h1>A little about me...</h1>
                <p>Information goes here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="parallaxContent">
                <h1>A little about me...</h1>
                <p>Information goes here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="parallaxContent">
                <h1>A little about me...</h1>
                <p>Information goes here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="parallaxContent">
                <h1>A little about me...</h1>
                <p>Information goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any help with be greatly appreciated! It's probably something simple I've missed somewhere maybe? Thank you!

Comment: Well, if you never want it to go further to the right than it is, maybe you should try to fix it somehow, opposed to using a float? As a float will change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your sidebar is `position: fixed` it is taken out of the regular flow of the layout, and float will not work the way you're expecting it to.
Try setting a left margin of 400px on your `#pageContent` div instead.
See below.

```css
/* Main CSS */
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Futura PT", sans-serif;
}

    /* Sidebar */
#sidebar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
}


/* Page Content */
#pageContentContainer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#pageContent {
    margin-left: 400px;
    width: 78%;
    background-color: #212121;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo/mdLogo.png"></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GRAPHIC DESIGN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3D MODELLING</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="socialLinks">
            <a href="#/" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-3x"></a>
            <a href="#/" class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></a>
            <a href="#/" class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-3x"></a>
        </div>
        <p>&copy; Macast Designs 2017</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="pageContentContainer">
        <div id="pageContent">
            <!-- Parallax -->
            <div class="parallaxImage1"></div>

            <div class="parallaxContent">
                <h1>A little about me...</h1>
                <p>Information goes here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="parallaxContent">
                <h1>A little about me...</h1>
                <p>Information goes here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="parallaxContent">
                <h1>A little about me...</h1>
                <p>Information goes here.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="parallaxContent">
                <h1>A little about me...</h1>
                <p>Information goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks so simple now! I will remember not to use floats then with fixed content; I can see what I was doing wrong now!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question.
But I think the problem is that you are using fixed values (px) you can diffuse the width in (%), but to be always adjusted you will have to use media queries.

```css
/* Main CSS */
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Futura PT", sans-serif;
}

    /* Sidebar */
#sidebar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
}


/* Page Content */
#pageContentContainer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#pageContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  left: 20%;
  background-color: #212121;
  display: inline-block;
}
```